# ReferenceError Articles is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have several schemas defined. Here's one that works fine:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose'), 
Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var NewsSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    route: String,
    remoteURL: String,
    articles: [{title: String, link: String, Image: String, contentSnippet: String}],
    retrieved: Date,
    dormant: { type: Boolean, default: false}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('News', NewsSchema);
```

Here's a second one that's nearly identical:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose'), 
Schema       = mongoose.Schema
// NewsSchema = new Schema({ name: String });   

var ArticlesSchema   = new Schema({
    title: String,
    link: String,
    pubDate: Date,
    image: String,
    contentSnippet: String,
    sourceName: String
    // sourceId: [ {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: NewsSchema}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Articles', ArticlesSchema);
```

I've loaded both of the modules at the top of my program, along with a bunch of other stuff like this:

```
players = require('./app/models/players'),
articles = require('./app/models/articles'),
```

If I create an instance of the first one with something like:

```
var player = new Players();
```

But if I try to create an instance of the second one with:

```
var item = new Articles();
```

I receive the error in the subject. In tracing the code I can see that the modules are in scope, so I don't believe it's something stupid like redefining a variable or something like that.

There are several questions of this nature posted here and none of the accepted answers apply.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why all those random spaces in your code ? You definitely need a linter my friend :)

Comment: It's the result of pasting into the code window here and then indenting to get the code to appear as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, upon further analysis, the working "model" no longer worked. It turns out that I had altered the case in the require statements at the top based on suggestions from Visual Studio Code. All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

instead of
sourceId: [ {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: NewsSchema}]
use
sourceId: [ {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'NewsSchema'}]
would solve your problem